# How to send push certificate to APNS while calling their APIs?

Tags: ios, spring-boot, ssl, apple-push-notifications

Have been stuck for sending push notification using apns push certificate from my server app (Spring Boot Application). Apple discussed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) on an overview of how we can send push with certificate but there is no technical detail about TLS communication (specially, on how I can send my push certificate to APNS and proceed API calls).

Anyone have any reference or article?

Comment: I need to send push to APNS using certificate without using any external library

Comment: have you tried this?\ https://gist.github.com/greencoder/16d1f8d7b0fed5b49cf64312ce2b72cc

Comment: @arturdev what would be the file format of cert in `--cert <certificate file>`? `.p12`, `.cert` or `.pem` ?

Comment: It can be a combined .pam or a combined .p12. You can use https://certifire.io/ to easily generate them for your app

Comment: @arturdev I am able to send push using curl, but I need to send from spring boot app. How can I do so?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring, but I think this will be a good start for your investigations:
https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

Comment: @arturdev I have used it, but it uses apns gateway and connect using port. I want to know guidelines for certificate based communication with APNS under TLS.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned your working on a Spring Boot application I'm assuming you're using Java and Maven.

Our back ends are also written in Java and I recently updated our push notification code by implementing [Pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy). It's *much much* easier to use a library that's battle tested and regularly updated than to write your own. I use pushy to send around 100k push notifications a day on a fairly weak server and have never had any issues with it.

It was fairly simple to implement. Their [README](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy/blob/master/README.md) is very useful but the summary is add pushy as a dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.eatthepath</groupId>
    <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's a simple example for your use-case using stolen code from the [README](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy/blob/master/README.md), I did add the comment though:

```
// Add these lines as class properties  

// This creates the object that handles the sending of the push notifications.
// Use ApnsClientBuilder.PRODUCTION_APNS_HOST to send pushes to App Store apps
final ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder()
        .setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST)
        .setClientCredentials(new File("/path/to/certificate.p12"), "p12-file-password")
        .build();  

// The push notification
final SimpleApnsPushNotification pushNotification;  

// In some method:  

// Creating the object that builds the APNs payload
final ApnsPayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = new ApnsPayloadBuilder();  

// setting the text of the push
payloadBuilder.setAlertBody("Example!");  

// Builds the anps payload for the push notification
final String payload = payloadBuilder.build();  

// The push token of the device you're sending the push to
final String token = TokenUtil.sanitizeTokenString("<efc7492 bdbd8209>");  

// Creating the push notification object using the push token, your app's bundle ID, and the APNs payload
pushNotification = new SimpleApnsPushNotification(token, "com.example.myApp", payload);  

try {
    // Asking the APNs client to send the notification 
    // and creating the future that will return the status 
    // of the push after it's sent.  
    // (It's a long line, sorry)
    final PushNotificationFuture<SimpleApnsPushNotification, PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification>> sendNotificationFuture = apnsClient.sendNotification(pushNotification);  

    // getting the response from APNs 
    final PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushNotificationResponse = sendNotificationFuture.get();
    if (pushNotificationResponse.isAccepted()) {
        System.out.println("Push notification accepted by APNs gateway.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Notification rejected by the APNs gateway: " +
                pushNotificationResponse.getRejectionReason());

        if (pushNotificationResponse.getTokenInvalidationTimestamp() != null) {
            System.out.println("\t…and the token is invalid as of " +
                pushNotificationResponse.getTokenInvalidationTimestamp());
        }
    }
} catch (final ExecutionException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to send push notification.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Don’t want to use any library though. Do you know how Pushy handle in the back, do they open sockets and proceed TLS handshaking and so on? Or they use different approach?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how they do it, but if you look through their `ApnsClientBuilder` class you can read some of the code where they set their credentials for TLS. The library is very well documented too, there should be some clues in there. If I had more free time, I'd search through it and figure it out, but unfortunately I do not.